# Is there any way to get all GET vars with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, get

First off, I do not want what is in the URL query. I want what PHP see's in the`$_GET` array.

This is because the URL query will not show all the params if `mod_rewrite` has been used to make pretty URLs

So is there a way to get the query string that would match exactly what is in the php `$_GET` array?

--

I came up with a way myself using PHP and JavaScript like so:

```
function query_string()
{
    <?php
        function assoc_array_to_string ($arr)
        {
            $a = array();
            foreach($arr as $key => $value)
            {
                $str = $key.'='.$value;
                $a[] = $str;
            }
            return implode("&",$a);
        }
    ?>
    return '<?=urlencode(assoc_array_to_string($_GET))?>';
}
```

...but I need to do this with just javascript if possible because I can't put PHP code in a `.js` file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse query string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

Comment: (Javascript can't reach the server. It won't know what `mod_rewrite` is doing. The above is the best solution you can do without server interaction.)

Comment: @KennyTM This isn't a duplicate because the above question is asking how to get what is in the url query string, I am not. I didn't know if they were stored anywhere retrievable from JS/DOM. I guess there is not, but a solution like Jhongs is better for my question then the link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't JavaScript "only see" the query string? How would client-side script know about any rewrite rules?

The only way I can think of is to use PHP -- echo it into a variable in an inline script in your main page rather than the JS file.

Answer (score 3):

In your page <head>:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var phpQueryParams = <?php print json_encode($_GET); ?>
</script>
```

Assuming at least PHP 5.2, otherwise use an [external package](http://pecl.php.net/package/json)

Comment: Although the returned JSON should be safe to use in terms of possible malicious strings, you should perhaps wrap the script content in <![CDATA[...]]>, combined with a str_replace to turn ]]> into ]"+"]> so that a string containing ]]> doesn't end the CDATA block.

If you decide not to use a JSON encoder you should be even more alert to the ways that a malicious query string could inject script into your page.

Answer (score 1):

The query string is found in `window.location.search`, but that's the raw query string. So if you run something like this:

```
(function () {
    QueryStr = {}
    QueryStr.raw = window.location.search.substr(1);
    var pairStrs = QueryStr.raw.split('&');
    QueryStr.val = {}
    for(var i=0,z=pairStrs.length; i < z; i++) {
        var pair = pairStrs[i].split('=');
        QueryStr.val[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
})();
```

You'd have something very much like `$_GET` in `QueryStr.val`.

Of course, you mention that you've mixed things up a bit using mod_rewrite, which is cool, but since we don't know your rewrite scheme, we can't help *specifically* with that.

However... *you* know your rewrite scheme, and you could probably modify the code I gave above to operate on some other part of `window.location`. My bet is that you'd want to split `window.location.pathname` on the `/` character instead of `&`.

Comment: Thanks, I could possibly (since I know the mod_write scheme) extract it from the URL using regex or something. However, I wanted a less ad-hoc way since I am panning on reusing this on multiple pages with different schemes. I think I may do something like Jhong suggests and just require a parameter in a function that can be passed in from outside the .js file with php. But thanks for the suggestion it is an idea I hadn't even thought of!