# How to retrieve the whole URL with parameters?

Tags: javascript

I need to retrieve the whole URL with the parameters as a string. For example, I need to retrieve the following URL:

```
http://www.keytometals.com/page.aspx?ID=CheckArticle&site=kts&LN=EN&NM=349
```

I've tried to use:

```
document.location.href,
document.URL,
window.location.href
```

but it retrieves just a part of URL:

```
http://www.keytometals.com/page.aspx
```

How to get the string containing the current URL as well as its parameters?

One update: I've used the

```
window.content.document.location.href
```

and I've got the following URL:

```
http://www.keytometals.com/page.aspx?ID=CheckArticle
```

Unfortunately, it is still the part of URL. Can somebody help me how to get the whole URL as a string?

Thanks!

Comment: What about just `window.location`?

Comment: window.location.href works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, nor window.location, neither window.location.href  doesn't work for me. I've tried online Javascript editor in  http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_write, writing the document.write(window.location.href), but the result is just:http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp

Comment: Are you trying in internet explorer?

Answer (score 7):

You should use `window.location.href` for the entire URL (including the query string).

Take a look at [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) for more information and other properties.

Here is another good StackOverflow post on how to [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript).

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work. When I try to retrieve the URL by using document.write(window.location.href) in                        http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_write  for example, I've got just the http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp . Just to mention that I use the Mozillla Firefox 4.

Answer (score 4):

You need just plain `document.location` -- that will include everything.  You'll need to write your own code to split it at the ? to get just the query string, and then split that into name/value pairs at each &.

EDIT:

Actually, you can use `location.search` as well.  Here's a snippet I wrote for this:

```
function loadQueryString(){ 
    var parameters = {}; 
    var searchString = location.search.substr(1); 
    var pairs = searchString.split("&"); 
    var parts;
    for(i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++){
        parts = pairs[i].split("=");
        var name = parts[0];
        var data = decodeURI(parts[1]);
        parameters[name] = data;
    }
    return parameters;
}

params = loadQueryString();
```

Comment: Why the `eval()` ? Bracket notation is you friend :)

Comment: @alex: Why didn't you fix it by yourself? :)

Comment: Hmm.  Well, I guess when I originally wrote it, I hadn't fully grasped the fact that arrays and objects are essentially identical in JS.  So yeah, bracket works just fine.

Comment: @Crozin: I don't know if modifying other people's code in answers is what I should be doing. :P

Comment: Can you, please, tell me how to write this params variable as a string? I've tried the document.write(params.toString), but it doesn't work.

Comment: @sonjafon Because `params` is an object literal, it doesn't have a default toString() method.  What are you trying to do?  It would help us to answer your questions if we knew what the end goal is.  Are you trying to write the complete URL into the document to show the end user?  Or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getQueryString() {
  var key = false, res = {}, itm = null;
  // get the query string without the ?
  var qs = location.search.substring(1);
  // check for the key as an argument
  if (arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0].length > 1)
    key = arguments[0];
  // make a regex pattern to grab key/value
  var pattern = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
  // loop the items in the query string, either
  // find a match to the argument, or build an object
  // with key/value pairs
  while (itm = pattern.exec(qs)) {
    if (key !== false && decodeURIComponent(itm[1]) === key)
      return decodeURIComponent(itm[2]);
    else if (key === false)
      res[decodeURIComponent(itm[1])] = decodeURIComponent(itm[2]);
  }

  return key === false ? res : null;
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
// get a single key (if it exists)
var t = getQueryString('site');
console.log(t);

// get the whole thing as an object
t = getQueryString();
console.log(t);
```

Comment: Can you, please, tell me how to retrieve this object as a string? When I try to write by using document.write(t) it just writes the "object Object"...

Comment: You can't write an object as a string, but you can write a property of an object as a string.  Using the second example above (get whole thing as an object), if you wanted to write the `site` key to the document, it would be `document.write(t.site)`.