# jquery, access page tab "with ajax content" via external hyperlink?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, hyperlink, jquery-ui-tabs

Im having trouble to open a page displaying a specific jquery tab that loads its content via ajax.

The problem is that jquery-ui opens tabs called by external links using the anchor hashtag but a ajax content tab anchor doesn't has one.

Any ideas

Thanks in advance.

Basicaly the same code in the jquery-ui demos
What i want is to have a link in my homepage that will open this other page already displaying tabX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            ajaxOptions: {
                        error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                            $( anchor.hash ).html(
                                "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                                "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
                        }
            }
        });
    });
});



<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="tab first_tab"><a id="tab1" href="tab1.html">dit doen we</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a id="tab2" href="tab2.html">disciplines</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a id="tab3" href="tab3.html">cases</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a id="tab4" href="tab4.html">uitgelicht</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: could you put some code in to clarify your question?

Comment: do you mean you want to have a link that opens a tab that loads its content via AJAX?

Comment: yes, but from another page in my site.

Comment: Do you mean the link is on another page, or do you mean the content to be loaded is another page?

Comment: :D the link(Last poject) is in my homepage, this link should take me to another page(our work page) that has a tab called Last Project. and this tab content is loaded via ajax. thanks :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a tab, you can use the `select` method on `.tabs()`, e.g. `$('#tabs').tabs('select', 1)` would select the 2nd tab (with a tab index of 1).

To open a page and tells it to select a tab, you will need to "pass the intention" somehow. If you're using AJAX for the page transition, then you can simply load the page and call `.tabs('select', tabIndex)`.

If you load the 2nd page without AJAX, you can pass in a variable with the querystring, e.g. `?loadTab=1` and parse for it in the page being loaded. [`location.search`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp) will give you the querystring. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript) will help you parse it.

So, on the 2nd page, you would have something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        ...
    });

    // code to parse the loadTab variable in the querystring

    if (typeof(loadTab) !== 'undefined' && parseInt(loadTab) !== 'NaN')
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', parseInt(loadTab));
}
```