# How to use multiple hashes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-bbq

Currently I use page numbers in hashes with Ben's Alman [jquery-hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).hashchange( function(){
      var hash = (location.hash) ? location.hash.slice(1) : 'page1';
      $.ajax({
          url: '/list/' + hash, // result url like page1, page2 etc.
```

Now I need to add there one more value - `filter`.
I think result hash URL can look like

```
#page1&filter=1-1-0 
#filter=1-1-0 (if page number is omitted)
#page1 (if filter is not defined)
```

**How to parse that?** I.e. how to understand if `page` is defined, if `filter` is defined (and what are the values - `1`, `1` and `0` - I need them separately)?

I was thinking about Ben's Alman [BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/), but (1) it looks too complicated for such simple task, (2) not sure how to use parameters (page1, page2 etc.) without values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple and unextediable parser for two hardcoded variables:

```
var hash_parts = location.hash.split('&', 2); //2 - limit, may be changed if more than two arguments

for(i in hash_parts) {
    if(hash_parts[i].indexOf("page") === 0) { //begins with "page"
        var current_page_number = hash_parts[i].substr(4);
    }
    else if(hash_parts[i].indexOf("filter") === 0) { //begins with "filter"
        var filter = hash_parts[i].split('=', 2);
        var filer_values = filter[1].split('-'); //filter_values == {'1', '1', '0'}
    }
}
```

You can easily make it universal.

Please, also take a look here: [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript) - just change `window.location.search.substring(1)` to hash.

Comment: Thanks! Another task I should resolve is how to define such hashes with javascript (i.e. I should understand if parameter is already added and if so, then I need to modify its value; otherwise - add parameter).

Comment: Manipulating hash is easy `document.location.hash = "somehash";`. So, you can do like that: `if(document.location.hash.length > 0) { ...  do something... }`.

Comment: Actually it is not so easy as you need to identify if some parm is already there and if so, then just update its value, otherwise - add it. I've used Ben's Alman BBQ plugin for the same.