# Parse string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, text-parsing, string-parsing

How can I parse this string on a javascript,

`var string = "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=322916384419110&set=a.265956512115091.68575.100001022542275&type=1";`

I just want to get the "**265956512115091**" on the string. I somehow parse this string but, still not enough to get what I wanted.

my code:

```
var newstring = string.match(/set=[^ ]+/)[0];
```

returns:

```
a.265956512115091.68575.100001022542275&type=1
```

Comment: To properly parse this, you should first dissect it into its parts (e,g, the key-values of the query string), then URL-decode the key and value, and only then extract the data you're interested in from the value with the key you're interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try this : 

  var g=string.match(/set=[a-z]\.([^.]+)/);

g[1] will have the value
```

http://jsbin.com/anuhog/edit#source

Answer (score 3):

You could use `split()` to modify your code like this:

```
var newstring = string.match(/set=[^ ]+/)[0].split(".")[1];
```

For a more generic approach to parsing query strings see:

[Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

Using the example illustrated there, you would do the following:

var newstring = getQueryVariable("set").split(".")[1];

Comment: My first instinct was to modify the regex too, but I thought the more general notion of parsing a query string was helpful.  Braveyard's answer answer (linked above) is based on split() and I just carried forward in kind.

Comment: If you want something generic, then by all means do apply proper URL decoding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges) in the regex.

```js
const str = 'http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=322916384419110&set=a.265956512115091.68575.100001022542275&type=1';

console.log(/&set=(.*)&/.exec(str)[1]);
```