# How to parse the querystring parameters in jquery when one of the param is having a special (&) character in its value

Tags: jquery

I have a URL with some querystring.

/mypage.html?errorcode=12345&name=something ™

I have a working code which can parse the querystring using jquery. But for the above example it is failing.

Any ideas on this so I can get the querystring pairs as:
errorcode = 12345 and 
name = something ™
Note: ™ has (&) in it. 
My code:

```
    $.extend({
        getUrlVars: function () {
            var vars = [], hash;
            var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
            return vars;
        },
        getUrlVar: function (name) {
            return $.getUrlVars()[name];
        }
    });
```

var paramValue = $.getUrlVar('errorcode');

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse query string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you have control of the url? Because the easiest solution is to properly encode it..

Comment: Yes. I Can encode the url
So it will be something like this:
%2FMy-offline.html%3Ferrorcode%3D12345%26name%3Dsomething%20%E2%84%A225A2

So how can I parse the querystring parameters here?

Comment: @Raj: dont encode the whole url, encode each paramname and value.

Comment: Thanks Paislee and prodigitalsonless.
SO I will only encode the values as I won't have any special character in parameter name.
It will look some thing like this:
offline.html?errorcode=12345&name=something%20%E2%84%A2 
My current code can get the param values. So how to decode them back?

Comment: Seems like working :) 
I have used decodeURIComponent function to decode the value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script lang=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>
function testQueryStrings()
{
window.location = “search.aspx?q=abc&type=advanced”;
}
</script>

<input type=”button” id=”btn” value=”Test Query Strings” onclick=”testQueryStrings()” />

<script lang=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>
var qrStr = window.location.search;
var spQrStr = qrStr.substring(1);
var arrQrStr = new Array();
// splits each of pair
var arr = spQrStr.split(‘&’);
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
// splits each of field-value pair
var index = arr[i].indexOf(‘=’);
var key = arr[i].substring(0,index);
var val = arr[i].substring(index+1);

// saves each of field-value pair in an array variable
arrQrStr[key] = val;
}

document.write(“<h1>Name parameter: “+arrQrStr["name"]+”. Role parameter: “+arrQrStr["role"]+”</h1>”);
```