# Extracting search queries from URL in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)
>   [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

```
http://www.example.org/search?q=example&another=test&again=more
```

How can I create three sepearate variables in jQuery with the values `example`, `test`, and `more`?

In other words, how can I extract a query from a URL based on its position (first, second, third, etc.) in the URL or based on the `&another=` part (not sure what it's called) of the query?

Comment: Not entirely sure what it is you want, can you give us example input and outputs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this method:

```
var query        = window.location.split('?')[1]; // or http://www.example.org/search?q=example&another=test&again=more
var query_obj    = unserialize(query);

function unserialize(query) {
    var pair, params = {};
    query = query.replace(/^\?/, '').split(/&/);
    for (pair in query) {
        pair = query[pair].split('=');
        params[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return params;
}
```

So you'll have your variables in the `query_obj` like this: `query_obj.test`

I found the function over the internet a while ago so I can't provide a link. Sorry and thanks to whoever published it first.

Answer (score 0):

I use an existing plugin for tasks like these: https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser