# DOM Manipulation help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

```
<div id="main">
<div class="navigate">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://localhost/xm/index.php"><span>xm</span></a> &#187;
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://localhost/xm/index.php?action=admin"><span>Admin</span></a> &#187;
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://localhost/xm/index.php?action=admin;change=name;random02342=randomvaluetoo320230"><span>change</span></a>
            .......
```

From this html code I have to get random generated data "random02342=randomvaluetoo320230" in variable, which is random generated both random0234 and random value too. How I can achieve this via Javascript (jquery or not)?

EDIT: random02342 and randomvaluetoo320230 is randomly server-side generated.. so its like every time new hash like 1stHash4324kjkjdas324324=And2ndAnotherHash324324asd23432

Comment: Did these values have pattern, e.g. if it always starts with 'random'? Or does it always have three query params? Do you know all other params in query string?

Comment: All other i know and third is only randomly generated like ?action=admin;change=name;1stHASH=2ndHASH and there is always '=' between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your comment:

```
var value = $('selector').attr('href').split(';')[2].split('=');
```

this will give you value[0] - name, and value[1] - value
However this is only if there 3 query params and the random one is the third

Also this might be usefull [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

Comment: You're welcome, really not good solution tho... it would be good to think about to refactor this

Answer (score 2):

This would get it, though it's probably not going to win any awards for elegance:

```
var m = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML.match(/random(\d+)=randomvaluetoo(\d+)/);
// m[1] and m[2] are the two random values.
```

Comment: Have you tried your example? This will suit if you have pattern for generated values

Comment: In my opinion you either need to remove '/' either to split query string first

Comment: "random" and "randomvaluetoo" is generated server-side randomly too.. =/

Comment: so its like HASH23434=anotherHASH2342

Comment: @Petar you should clarify this in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
var first, second;

var q = $('.navigate ul li a[href*="change=name"]').attr('href').split(';').filter(
    function() {
        return this.contains('random');
    }
).join().replace(/[a-zA-z]/g, '').split('=');

first = q[0];
second = q[1];
```