# JS how to take parameter name from URL

Tags: jquery

I am currently in a page that its url is `http://localhost:49852/Default.aspx?MID=17`

in this page i have the following code

```
<a href="Configure.aspx"><span class="ico gray shadow gear"></span>Configure</a>
```

I would like that once the user will click on `Configure` link the MID parameter from the URL will be cropped and the user will be redirected to

```
http://localhost:49852/Configure.aspx?MID=17
```

This is the JS Code

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)')
            .exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

How do i bind it all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I think you should give your href an id for easy access like:

```
<a href="Configure.aspx" id="configure"><span class="ico gray shadow gear"></span>Configure</a>
```

Then you should be able to change the property with:

```
$(function() {
    var href = $("#configure").attr("href");
    $("#configure").attr("href", href + getParameterByName("MID"))
});
```

This will change the actual href. You could probably just as easily override the click method, but this might be more extensible if you want to change it from the configure link to all links or something.

Comment: clean! would prefer this method.

Comment: Cleaner solution than using a click-event listener like in my example +1

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a click-event listener on the element, and when clicked, you modify `window.location` to perform the redirect. Something like this:

```
$(function () {
   // You might need to use a better selector here, 
   // add an ID to the span element and select on that instead
   $("span.ico").on("click", function () {
      window.location.href = "Configure.aspx?MID=" + getParameterByName("MID");
      return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the MID from QueryString with this nice function 
as explained at [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)
and build a new URL with it.

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
}
```

like ;

```
var mid = getQueryVariable(MID);
var url = 'http://localhost:49852/Configure.aspx?MID='+mid;
location.href=url;
```