# Splitting a key value pair response seperated by a '&' using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

I have a response that I receive from the server in this format - `Status=105&Accno=1458874455&Name=XYZ&Bal=5,888.00`
Here '&' signifies separator.

I need to iterate through the string response and split this string in JavaScript based on the '&' and get the values and store them as :

```
Status=105
Accno=1458874455
Name=XYZ
Bal=5,888.00
```

so that I can populate them in the respective textbox and drop down.

I am using jQuery and AJAX for receiving the response.

Answer (score 5):

You can use split to get the data out:

```
data = response.split("&");
```

Once you have the data in the format "key=value", you can split again and add to dictionary:

```
processed_data = new Object();

for(i = 0; i < data.length, i++){
    m = data[i].split("=");
    processed_data[m[0]] = m[1];
}
```

You can use the dictionary like:

```
processed_data["Status"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **str.split("&")** for separating each key value pair. Then use **str.split("=")** to separate key from pair.