# Javascript : expected error

Tags: javascript

I am unable to decipher the error message `Expected :`. It occurs when it attempts to execute the code below. I have a string of characters e.g. "Joe":"HR" being passed to it

```
var p = {
    "\"" + m[0] + "\"" + " : " + "\"" + (m[0] = m[1]) + "\""
};
```

**Additional code**

```
for (var key in p) 
            {
                if (p.hasOwnProperty(key))
                {
                client = selectedPackage.Elements.AddNew(key, p[key]);
                client.Update();
                }
            }
```

Comment: `=` in object key assignment?

Comment: What is that code supposed to do?

Comment: @redV - I'm following an example of whether i have a string of characters e.g. "Joe":"HR" and need to parse them as name value pairs. The example i came across is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020941/splitting-a-key-value-pair-response-seperated-by-a-using-javascript

Comment: @Barmar - It's meant to take a string of characters and parse it. I have added the additional code in the post.

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the question you referenced.

Comment: @Barmar - Apologies. I have added it now.

Comment: I mean there's nothing in that question that looks like your `var p = ...` statement. The answer in that question shows how to set properties that are computed from a string, why aren't you following it?

Comment: @Barmar - Sorry Barmar. Am new at this. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: You said you got this code from the other question. I looked at that question and I don't see anything like the code you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` is an object, so it expects a value for the key:

```
{
    "key": "value"
}
```

In your case, the key is `"\"" + m[0] + "\"" + " : " + "\"" + (m[0] = m[1]) + "\""` (which is actually invalid, the error is a little unclear on this), so you need to specify a value as well.

I suspect you want this (from your string, which looks like JSON):

```
var p = { };
p[m[0]] = m[1];
```

Comment: You also can't use an expression as the key in an object literal, the key has to be an identifier or a literal string.

Comment: So it looks like he's missing the key, and that concatenation should be the value.

Comment: @Tom Leese - All i get is `[object Object]`.

Comment: As Barmar said, that's what you get when you try to get a string representation of an object. Sounds like this is the output from a JavaScript console?

Comment: @Tom Leese - That's correct and it throws an error when it hits the next block of code.

Comment: @Tom Leese - When it reaches `client = selectedPackage.Elements.AddNew(key, p[key]);` The error i get is `invalid type`

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong, perhaps the error is in `AddNew` itself? You could try doing `console.log(key, p[key]);` on in the for loop to get more information.

Comment: @Tom Leese  - I could show you the entire code if i had the option for a chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48990/discussion-between-peanutsmonkey-and-tom-leese)

Comment: @Tom Leese - Thanks so much for your help. I was able to resolve it. Interestingly enough when i keyed in the values again into the text file, they worked. I don't why but they did.

Answer (score 3):

You're defining an object, but only have a key without value, e.g. you're trying to do:

```
var p = {
   key : value
}
```

But your code is only

```
var p = {
   key
}
```

You have a `:`, but since it's inside a string (`" : "`), it doesn't count.

Comment: well, if that `" : "` is supposed to be the the key:value separator, then then `... + " : " + ...` into `... : ...` instead.

Comment: I tried `"\"" + m[0] + "\"" + : + "\"" + (m[0] = m[1]) + "\""` and it doesn't work either

Comment: remove the `+`. you're trying to concatenate a bare `:` now, which is illegal syntax.

Comment: I tried `var p = {
    "\"" + m[0] + "\"" : "\"" + (m[0] = m[1]) + "\""
};` and it still throws an error. Can you post an example? I may be overlooking something.

Comment: Why are you concatting all those quotes, and WHY are you doing an assignment (`m[0]=m[1]`) in there?

Comment: Because i have tried `m[0] : (m[0] = m[1])` and it fails as well.

Comment: but WHY do you want the value of m[0] to be used as a key? and why are you OVERWRITING that value in the value section? `m[0] = m[1]` stuffs the value of m[1] into m[0].

Comment: The reason is `m[0] ` is the key e.g. Joe and `m[0] = m[1]` is the value.

Comment: no. `m[0] = m[1]` is AN ASSIGNMENT. You're overwriting `Joe` with whatever was in `m[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create an object with a variable key and value by concatenating the text of a literal. You have to use array-style assignment:

```
var p = {};
p[m[0]] = m[1];
```

Comment: I tried that and all it returns is `[object Object]`

Comment: That's what an object looks like when you try to display it as a string.

Comment: How do i know if the values are being passed in that case because i get an error at `client = selectedPackage.Elements.AddNew(key, p[key]);`?  The error i get is `invalid type`

Comment: If this is the Firefox Console, you should be able to click on `[object Object]` to get more information about it.

Comment: @Tom Leese - Unfortunately i can't as it's a script editor of a third-party tool so debugging is limited.