# Javascript regex value search

Tags: javascript, regex

After reading the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex), I tried to get the value by regex as below:

```
var myString = "<a href='/search.html?id=HDJ&area=ASD&estate=JKG&ppt=3'></a>";
var myRegexp = /&estate=(.*?)(?:\s|$)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
match[1]
```

The result was `JKG&propertytype=3'></a>`, but I only want `JKG`. Strictly speaking I want the value between `&estate=` and `&ppt` Could someone suggest how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Regular Expression:**

```
/&estate=(.*?)&ppt=/g
```

**Note:** I wouldn't recommend using regular expressions to parse query strings. It's brittle. Consider if the variables in the query string change order. If that can be the case, I recommend reading - [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript).

Comment: +1 for the recommended reading. I have used and loved that snippet.

Answer (score 2):

do:

```
var myString = "<a href='/search.html?id=HDJ&area=ASD&estate=JKG&ppt=3'></a>";
var myRegexp = /estate=(.*)&ppt=/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log( match[1] );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but what is the different between `/estate=(.*)&ppt=/g;` and `/estate=(.*?)&ppt=/g;`?

Comment: Charles Yeung: `* = 0 or more times` and  `? = 0 or 1 times`  Therefore, having `?` is redundant for `*?`  To verify, enter and test your regex [**here**](http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex#).

Comment: Screenshot for above regex [http://i.stack.imgur.com/x1kdU.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x1kdU.png)

Comment: @arttronics, individual that is correct. But together `*?` means a *non-greedy* 0 or more match.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, I forgot to look at that as a `group`. So then, `(RegExp?)` is non-greedy, while as you say `(*?)` is *non-greedy* 0 or more times, I certainly agree. However, I don't see a logical difference in your regex requiring it to be greedy to function correctly. Perchance when your regex is part of another group, then it sings it's use. Am I mistaken that it needs to be greedy as it stands?

Comment: I think you're still not understanding the difference. You may want to [read up](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Comment: Fine. Don't answer my question then.

Answer (score 1):

If only the solution is important then you can use the following:

```
var myString = "<a href='/search.html?id=HDJ&area=ASD&estate=JKG&ppt=3'></a>";
var indx1 = mystring.indexOf("&estate=") + 8;
var indx2 = mystring.indexOf("&ppt");
var neededString = mystring.substring(indx1, indx2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude ampersands from the selection:

```
var myRegexp = /&estate=([^&]+)/g;
```

You might want to change it to this, in case estate is the first parameter:

```
var myRegexp = /[\?&]estate=([^&]+)/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RF2gX/)

Based on your result value, just `split` it at the ampersand, ***no new or alternate regex required.***

**JavaScript:**

```js
var myString = "<a href='/search.html?id=HDJ&area=ASD&estate=JKG&ppt=3'></a>";
var myRegexp = /&estate=(.*?)(?:\s|$)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);

var value = match[1].split('&')[0];

alert( value );
```