# get only part of current url and redirect with javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, geoip

I need get only this part of current url and redirect after 5 seconds...

example of current url:

```
http://www.page.com/?archive=filename
```

i need get only **filename** and put in javascript code

here my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var country,url;
country = geoip_country_code()
if(country=="US"){
    url="http://www.page.com/1.php?archive=filename";
} else if (country == "UK") {
    url="http://www.page.com/2.php?archive=filename";
} else if (country == "ES") {
    url="http://www.page.com/3.php?archive=filename";
}
setTimeout("location.href = url;",5000);
</script>
```

please i need help with this code, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values):

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var country, 
    url, 
    codemap = { 
        US: 1,
        UK: 2,
        ES: 3
    };

url = "http://www.page.com/" + codemap[geoip_country_code()] + ".php?archive=" + getParameterByName('archive');

setTimeout(function () { location.href = url; },5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a previous question on parsing query strings in JavaScript.  That one's already marked as a duplicate, so there's undoubtedly more info out there.  If this doesn't help, the keywords you want to search for are "Parse query string in JavaScript".

[Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)