# Javascript that can handle parsing query strings with one to many key/value pairs?

Tags: javascript, query-string

New to Javascript here and from looking through [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript), I was not sure which answer could fit my needs.

I need a javascript solution that allows me to parse key/value pairs with multiple values for a single key. Example: ?key1=value1&key1=value2

Comment: Hey.  I think you'll find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript

Comment: There are lots of methods here for doing it the standard way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values/3855394#3855394 - You should then have your initial values be arrays and `push` to them each time instead of replacing the key.