# Load new page using d3

Tags: html, d3.js

I have an SVG map of the U.S., and I would like to make it so that when you click on a state, a new page loads with information about that state.

Here is my code that fills the states (the paths are already created); it's a choropleth so the color is based on murder rates.

`d3.selectAll("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
         return color(murderrates[codes.indexOf(this.id)])
         })
    .on("click", **load(new page, this.id)**)`

The pseudo code between the asterisks is what I'd like to accomplish: when the state is clicked, open a new page and tell it which state was clicked so it knows what information to display. In other words, the new page should be able to "accept an argument" - the state - so it knows what to display.

Edit: I do not have a different page to load for each state. Instead, it is one page that could display 50 different things depending on which state caused it to load. So let's say I had a variable called `origin` in my new page. I would like the value of `origin` to be set to `this.id` upon loading.

Comment: `window.location = "http://yourdomain.com/url/for/states?id=" + this.id;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of @StephenThomas's comment, you can define a function `loadPage` that uses `this.id` to change the `window.location`:

```
function loadPage(){
    window.location = URL + "?origin=" + this.id;
}
```

This will open a new page where the query parameter `"origin"` will contain `this.id`. You can then parse the query param, e.g. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript).

Then pass that function as the callback to the onclick, as D3 will automatically set the value of `this` to the appropriate element:

```
.on("click", loadPage)
```

Comment: @pwerth: do you mean something like `return URL + "&origin=" + this.id`? This will store `this.id` in a query param in the new page, which you can retrieve using Javascript, e.g. [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript).

Comment: yes, something like that would work. however, when I try `return window.location = URL + "&origin=" + this.id` it says webpage not found. I think it's looking for a file that has that url and none exists

Comment: @pwerth: what URL are you using? (Also, you don't need to `return`, I removed that from my answer.)

Comment: @pwerth: Argh, sorry about that, that would do it :)

Comment: no worries. thanks for the help, i'd upvote your answer but i don't have enough rep