# pass data between two html pages using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I pass variables between two html pages using jQuery?

file1.html

```html
<form>
  First name : <input type="text" id="firstname"/>
</form>
```

file2.html:

```
<p> <!--retrieve firstname here --> </p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass JavaScript variable between two HTML pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748076/pass-javascript-variable-between-two-html-pages)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want pass data by submitting the form?

Comment: I do not know how to submit without using php which i don't want to use.

Comment: HTML5 session and local variables will do it for you

Comment: do you mind showing me how ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage:

```
// Store (on first page)
localStorage.setItem("firstname", "Smith");

// Retrieve (on second page)
var firstname = localStorage.getItem("firstname");
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp