# accessing global variable of window in another window in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have opened a separate window from a page using `window.open(url);`.I have set some global variables inside the first window. Now I want to access these variables inside my new window. How can I do it? or is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: use $localstorage or ngStorage in angularjs

Comment: Are you using both AngularJS and backbone.js?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible via the `window.opener` object.

For example: If you have this code in an HTML file:

```
// JavaScript code in index.html file
window.myVariable = 'variable value';
window.open('child.html');
```

The `myVariable` variable is accessible in the child.html file

```
// JavaScript code in child.html file
console.log(window.opener.myVariable); // outputs 'variable value'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Querystrings` to achieve this.  There are a number of links available with valuable resources if you do so:

[how to exchange variables between two HTML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724106/how-to-exchange-variables-between-two-html-pages)

[Pass JavaScript variable between two HTML pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748076/pass-javascript-variable-between-two-html-pages)

[Passing JavaScript data values between 2 HTML pages.](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/795191/Passing-JavaScript-data-values-between-HTML-pages)

A basic usage example is the following:

*Screen1.html (passing data from):*

```
function sendData() 
{      
  window.location = "Screen2.html?" + dataToBeSent;

}
```

*Screen2.html (receiving data):*

```
var query = window.location.search;
```

Comment: Please explain how to use `Querystrings` in the answer itself. Without it this is just a bunch of external links and not really an answer.

Comment: See edits.. Although there is much more material available on how to extract specific data types.