# How to extract the numeric string in a url

Tags: javascript, regex

I am wondering how to extract the numeric string in a url using javascript? say to get 1234 in `http://example.com?uid=1234`

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

use regular expressions. \d is any digit, + is 1 or more.

```
var str = 'http://example.com?uid=1234';
var regexp = /\d+/;

str = str.match(regexp);

console.log(parseInt(str));
```