# JavaScript convert String to object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Folks, using js libraries such as `underscore`,`underscore.string`, or `lodash`, I'd like to convert the following String to an Object

```
'animals=cat&dogs&horses&fish=salmon&tuna';
```

The following are constant: `animals` and `fish`.  Separator is `=`

The result should look like:

```
{
    animals: 'cats&dogs&horses',
    fish: 'salmon&tona'
}
```

`animals` and `fish` can occur in the string in any order.

Thanks!

PS  Its not a duplicate of [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)...  as the requirements are to return an object for later parsing...

Comment: this is a duplicate.
see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript

Comment: and btw , in Javascript Strings ARE objects. correct title would be : convert query into a key-value object

Comment: @david, great hunch, but i really need to escape `&` hence using `request._parsedUrl.query` instead of `request.query`.  Thanks !  So how can i get the result im looking for? :)

Comment: dud you look in the link?

Comment: absolutely, i am not trying to parse a request in this method.   its a helper function which literally needs to do what i've asked

Comment: ok , so put an example which reflect your need. what you posted is clearly a url-query

Comment: ok, imagine you need to escape '&' using _.escape and you'll be stuck

Comment: so just use _.unescape and continue from there like the link suggest

Comment: This is a malformed query string. However, or whoever, or wherever it came from, the `&` needs to be encoded for it be parsable.

Comment: @torazaburo, query string is correct in my case, hence me posting the question.  I really would like someone to answer the question instead of linking to other questions on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Why not use regex capture groups to find what you want?

Comment: @torazaburo unfortunately i can not change the clients calling the api to encode the & :)  so back to the original question...

Comment: @evolutionxbox how :)  example?

Comment: I just tried... unless you escape the "&" like this, `animals=cat%26dogs%26horses&fish=salmon%26tuna`. You cannot parse this string and separate the values into what you want, url or not.

Comment: @Cmag As it stands, the string is unparseable and ambiguous. You can not spin gold out of straw. There is a bug in the program generating this string, which needs to get fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick vanilla js solution:

```js
function parseQuery (string) {
  var result = {}, components, i, firstPair, current;
  components = string.split("&");

  for (i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
    if (components[i].indexOf("=") !== -1) {
      if (typeof current !== "undefined") {
        result[current] = result[current].join("&");
      }
      firstPair = components[i].split("=");
      current = firstPair[0];
      result[current] = [firstPair[1]];
    } else {
      result[current].push(components[i]);
    }
  }

  result[current] = result[current].join("&");

  return result;
}
```

Comment: But this won't give the desired results, because the ampersands are used inside the values themselves and for separating the values.

Comment: It works on the sample and should work on any other of the pattern :`key=val&val&key=val&val`. Components with keys are distinguished by checking whether they contain `=`; this gets around the ambiguity of the ampersands.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more compact:

```
var x = 'animals=cat&dogs&horses&fish=salmon&tuna';
```

Split the string using the feature of `split` which preserves splitters which are groups in the splitting regexp. We split on anything which starts at the beginning of the string or with a `&`, and contains an `=` at the end:

```
var pieces = x.split(/((?:^|&)\w+=)/) . filter(Boolean);
>> ["animals=", "cat&dogs&horses", "&fish=", "salmon&tuna"]
```

The result will be an array of interspersed keynames and values. Process this into an object:

```
var result = {};
for (var i=0; i<pieces.length; i+=2) { 
    result[pieces[i].replace(/^&|=$/g, '')] = pieces[i+1];
}
```