# jQuery - Get url hash

Tags: jquery

I have three tabs on a page

- Latest
- Expired
- Pending

When each tab is active, a hash is added to the url:

http://example.com/com/#latest

I am trying to add pagination fore each tab. So I was thinking of doing something like this:

http://example.com/com/#latest?p=5

But I don't know how to get the hash value by itself. Using `$(location).attr('hash')` returns `#latest?p=5`

```
if( $(location).attr('hash') ) {
    var tab = $(location).attr('hash');
}else{
    var tab = "#latest";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getting hash

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

getting `latest`

```
var active = hash.match(/\#(\w+)/)[1];
```

getting page number

```
var num = hash.match(/p=(\d+)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 5):

It is a JavaScript property

```
 window.location.hash
```

Then you need to parse your string. If you use standard query string notation you can parse it with code from [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Can you explain "standard query string notation" ?

Answer (score 1):

There are important details overseen on the other answers:

- FireFox returns the hash value URL encoded
- You get the hash value, including the initial hash

To solve the Firefox problem, you need to read it this way:

```
var hashValue = decodeURI(window.location.hash);
```

which is also safe for the other browsers.

If you want to get the value without the initial has symbol `#`, you simply have to do this:

```
var hashValue = decodeURI(window.location.hash).substr(1);
```