# Option selected value onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello this is my current code:

```
<select id="link_course">
<option value="">Select Course</option>
<option value="ALL">ALL</option>
<option value="BSIT" selected>BSIT</option>
<option value="BSA">BSA</option>
<option value="BSBA">BSBA</option>
<option value="BSHRTM">BSHRTM</option>
</select>

<script>
    $("#link_course").change(function()
          {
              document.location.href = "home.php?course=" + $(this).val();

        });
</script>
```

If you click any of those options, for example BSBA, it will go to home.php?course=BSBA, and also you can see that the `selected` attribute is on the option BSIT. What I wanted to do is whenever I click another link, for example BSHRTM, the `selected` attribute will go to BSHRTM like it would be `<option value="BSHRTM" selected>BSHRTM</option>`. Any thoughts?

Comment: So you want first link will go `home.php?course=Link_value` and second one should go only `linkvalue`??

Comment: Not clear ..what are you asking?? explain more

Comment: @Manwal I want to get the current course for like $_GET['course'] then set the attribute to the option with that current course selected

Comment: check this answer how to get params from URL 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do selection via JavaScript :

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

if(getQueryVariable('course') != false) {
    $('#link_course option[value="' + getQueryVariable('course') + '"]').prop('selected', true);
}
```

[Reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

After loading the new page, you need to run JavaScript code to set the value on the correct item from the list.

Comment: Since you're already using JQuery, have you tried searching for information about running code on page load? Google is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href`to get current URL. Then check on which page is user currently on and finally select corresponding option.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('home.php?course=BSHRTM)') != -1) {
   $('select#link_course option[value=BSHRTM]').attr("selected","selected");
}
```

To avoid code duplication see [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in PHP:

```
<option value="BSHRTM" <?php if($course == 'BSHRTM') echo 'selected';?>>
```

*Supposing that you previsously set `$course = $_GET['course'];`*

Comment: pls add in answer how you get $course . using $_GET method

Comment: so every option I will add like <?php if($course == 'BSHRTM') echo 'selected';?> right?

Comment: Exactly (or better, use an array and a for loop)

Comment: I want to do it on the client-side

Comment: Ok (and please you edit your question to add this important information...)