# How to keep the current tab active in Jquery after reload the page also for dynamic tabs

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.scroll_nav li a').click(function(){
      $('li a').removeClass("active_scroll");
      $(this).addClass('active_scroll');
    $('ul li .btn-br_all_gun').click(function(){
      $('li a').removeClass("active_scroll");
        
  });
        
  });
});
```

```html
<li><a href="{% url 'gun:browse_gun' %}" class="btn btn-br_all_gun">Browse All Your Guns</a></li>
    
{% for gunName in gunModelUserTieIn %}
     <li><a href="#">{{ gunName.gun_model.model_name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Browse all gun button is the static button. and remaining tabs are came dynamically in user select cases. Here When i click the other tabs the page is reloading that's why it will again shows the first:li a tab is active. how to solve this problem

Comment: You need to store the active tab somewhere (eg a cookie, a fragmentin the URL, session/local storage) and then retrieve the state and set the classes on the tabs based on that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907609/how-to-keep-active-class-when-changing-pages answered before

Comment: Can also use different url hashes in href and parse url hash on page load

Answer (score 0):

```
  #This code will work

  $("#innovs_tabs").tabs({
      active: localStorage.getItem("currentIdx"),
      activate: function(event, ui) {
      localStorage.setItem("currentIdx", $(this).tabs('option', 'active'));
    }
  });
```

Comment: You should say _why_ this code works and not only that it does.