# How to change the active class when clicking on other link?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

There are 2 scenarios for this issue:

1. with using preventDefault()
2. Without using preventDefault()

I am changing the active class using jQuery.

What happens when I use preventDefault():

[image]

As you can see, I clicked on About us link, it shows active after clicking but the content is not displaying.

What happens when I don't use preventDefault():

[image]

As you can see, here I clicked on About us link, content is displaying properly but the active class still there in a Home link.

How to sort out this issue? I found this link:

[How to change active class while click to another link in bootstrap use jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975922/how-to-change-active-class-while-click-to-another-link-in-bootstrap-use-jquery)

but here the issue is not resolved. I tried every jQuery but it didn't work.

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">

                        <div class="container-fluid">

                             <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                               </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="Default.aspx"><img src="images/layout/check1.png" style="width:310px;padding-left:82px;height:60px;" class="img-responsive" alt="dubaiexporters.com"/>
                                </a>
                          </div>
                      <div id="navbar2" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="active" style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="menu" style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="advertize.aspx">Advertise</a></li>                           
                            <li class="dropdown" style="font-family:Merriweather;">
                              <a href="exhibition.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Exhibitions <span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                  <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="dubaiexhibitions.aspx">Trade fairs in U.A.E</a></li>
                                   <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="exhibition.aspx">Trade fairs worldwide</a></li>
                                  <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="addexhibition.aspx">Add Your Event</a></li>             
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                              <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="subscribe.aspx">Subscribe</a></li>
                              <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="member_benefits.aspx">Memberships</a></li>
                              <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="aboutus.aspx">About us</a></li>
                              <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="news.aspx">News</a></li>
                              <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="contactus.aspx">Contact us</a></li>
                              <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="media_partners.aspx">Partners</a></li>
                              <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="login.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>


                         </ul>                      
                          <a href="addlisting.aspx" target="_blank" class="floatingbanner"></a>
                       </div>

      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                  </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->



              </nav>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.nav li a').click(function (e) {
                $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
                var $parent = $(this).parent();
                $parent.addClass('active');
                //e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

Comment: jquery is client side. if you want to load the new page after you click it, the link will be re-loaded and the class removed.  You will either have to ajax in the content of the new page, or use a server side language to add the class, or re-add the class on page load using jquery (I would recommend option 2)

Comment: @Pete Is there any solution for this or any other link related to this issue?

Comment: @Pete Yes...i m using c#

Comment: [c# mvc example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410623/how-to-add-active-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc), [js example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060467/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/80556/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep active class when changing pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907609/how-to-keep-active-class-when-changing-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have done it by using the code behind:

```
<li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                               <li id="test1" style="font-family:Merriweather;" runat="server"><a href="advertize.aspx">Advertise</a></li>                              
                            <li id="test2" class="dropdown" style="font-family:Merriweather;" runat="server">
                              <a href="exhibition.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Exhibitions <span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                  <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="dubaiexhibitions.aspx">Trade fairs in U.A.E</a></li>
                                   <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="exhibition.aspx">Trade fairs worldwide</a></li>
                                  <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="addexhibition.aspx">Add Your Event</a></li>             
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                              <li id="test3" style="font-family:Merriweather;" runat="server"><a href="subscribe.aspx">Subscribe</a></li>
                              <li id="test4" style="font-family:Merriweather;" runat="server"><a href="member_benefits.aspx">Memberships</a></li>
                              <li id="test5" style="font-family:Merriweather;" runat="server"><a href="aboutus.aspx">About us</a></li>
                              <li id="test6" style="font-family:Merriweather;" runat="server"><a href="news.aspx">News</a></li>
                              <li id="test7" style="font-family:Merriweather;" runat="server"><a href="contactus.aspx">Contact us</a></li>
                              <li id="test8" style="font-family:Merriweather;" runat="server"><a href="media_partners.aspx">Partners</a></li>
                              <li id="test9" style="font-family:Merriweather;" runat="server"><a href="login.aspx" runat="server"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
```

here i added id to `li` and `runat="server"`

Code Behind:

```
Page Load
{
       String activepage = Request.RawUrl;
        if (activepage.Contains("advertize.aspx"))
        {
            test1.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
       else if (activepage.Contains("subscribe.aspx"))
        {
            test3.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        else if (activepage.Contains("member_benefits.aspx"))
        {
            test4.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        else if (activepage.Contains("aboutus.aspx"))
        {
            test5.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        else if (activepage.Contains("news.aspx"))
        {
            test6.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        else if (activepage.Contains("contactus.aspx"))
        {
            test7.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        else if (activepage.Contains("media_partners.aspx"))
        {
            test8.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        else if (activepage.Contains("login.aspx"))
        {
            test9.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on click of menu, you are loading page which is specified in `href` attribute of anchor tag. hence added active class in clicked event handler will not hold true as page is refreshing.
You can make use of `localStorage` and save index of clicked `li` and accordingly add `active` class. Try below jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var index = localStorage.getItem('liIndex');
            if(index) {
               $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
               $('.nav li:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
            }
            $('.nav li a').click(function (e) {
                var $parent = $(this).parent();
                localStorage.setItem('liIndex', $parent.index());
            });
        });
```

Same can be achieved using cookies, see below code

```
    function setCookie(key, value) {
      var expires = new Date();
      expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (value * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
    }

    function getCookie(key) {
        var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
        return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
            var index = getCookie('liIndex');
            if(index) {
               $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
               $('.nav li:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
            }
            $('.nav li a').click(function (e) {
                var $parent = $(this).parent();
                setCookie('liIndex', $parent.index());
            });
 });
```

Comment: have you tried same logic with cookies where you can store index of last clicked li parent and add / remove active class accordingly?

Comment: i tried this but it dint worked.....now i am trying to do it by using code behind..