# Change Parameters by Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that contains URL like parameters:

```
var params="f5=212&f1=255&f3=400&f6=789&f9=243"
```

I want to change the value of `f1`, say from `255` to `355`.

But the problem is parameters are dynamic and location of individual parameter changes. Below are possible cases:

```
var params="f1=456&f5=212&f3=400&f6=789&f9=243"
var params="f5=212&f1=451&f3=400&f6=789&f9=243"
var params="f5=212&f3=400&f1=255&f6=789&f9=243"
var params="f5=212&f3=400&f6=789&f9=243&f1=123"
```

How can I create the regex to change `f1` value correctly by JavaScript?

Comment: so you want to increase the f1 value by 100?

Comment: No just want to change it by any value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse query string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture what is immediately before f1:

```
params = params.replace(/(^|&)f1=[^&]*/, '$1f1=355');
```

Comment: Judging from the sample cases capturing what's before f1 doesn't seem necessary (but won't hurt of course).

Comment: Looks great Casimir. But would you mind sharing the code for replacing the any value that f1 has? It would be great if it is not looking for only integers. I will accept your answer then.

Comment: With the above information added I take my comment back, obviously.

Comment: @Jessie: udapted for any kind of value *(`[^&]` all that is not a `&`)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
var new_var = 355;
params = params.replace(/f1=[0-9]{3}/,'f1='+new_var);
```