# Javascript get query string values using non-capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this query string:

```
?cgan=1&product_cats=mens-jeans,shirts&product_tags=fall,classic-style&attr_color=charcoal,brown&attr_size=large,x-small&cnep=0
```

How can I extract the values from only these param types `'product_cat, product_tag, attr_color, attr_size'` returning only `'mens-jeans,shirts,fall,classic-style,charcoal,brown,large,x-small`?

I tried using a non-capturing group for the param types and capturing group for just the values, but its returning both.

```
(?:product_cats=|product_tags=|attr\w+=)(\w|,|-)+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect tha values using

```
(?:product_cats|product_tags|attr\w+)=([\w,-]+)
```

Mind that a character class (`[\w,-]+`) is much more efficient than a list of alternatives (`(\w|,|-)*`), and we avoid the issue of capturing just the last single character.

Here is a code sample:

```js
var re = /(?:product_cats|product_tags|attr\w+)=([\w,-]+)/g; 
var str = '?cgan=1&product_cats=mens-jeans,shirts&product_tags=fall,classic-style&attr_color=charcoal,brown&attr_size=large,x-small&cnep=0';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res.join(",");
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: This works great. Do you think this is an efficient way to achieve this. Thanks for tips on character classes.

Comment: If you are using plain JS, this is a good way to obtain data from your query string. If you prefer a function that would return values by a provided key name, you can have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2091331/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

You can use following simple regex :

```
/&\w+=([\w,-]+)/g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oA7iR3/1)

You need to return the result of capture group and split them with `,`.

```
var mystr="?cgan=1&product_cats=mens-jeans,shirts&product_tags=fall,classic-style&attr_color=charcoal,brown&attr_size=large,x-small&cnep=0
";
var myStringArray = mystr.match(/&\w+=([\w,-]+)/g);
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length-1; //-1 is because of that the last match is 0
var indices = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    indices.push(myStringArray[i].split(','));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a jQuery method [param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
/(?:product_cats|product_tag|attr_color|attr_size)=[^,]+/g
```

- `(?:product_cats|product_tag|attr_color|attr_size)` will match `product_cats` or `product_tag` or `attr_color` or `attr_size)`
- `=` Matches an equals
- `[^,]` Negated character class matches anything other than a `,`. Basically it matches till the next `,`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zO8xP9/1)

**Test**

```
string = "?cgan=1&product_cats=mens-jeans,shirts&product_tags=fall,classic-style&attr_color=charcoal,brown&attr_size=large,x-small&cnep=0";

matched = string.match(/(product_cats|product_tag|attr_color|attr_size)=[^,]+/g);  

for (i in matched)
{
console.log(matched[i].split("=")[1]);
}
```

will produce output as

```
mens-jeans
charcoal
large
```

Comment: You are not using groups, so I would set a non-capturing group around the list of alternatives in this regex. And this regex won't do the job correctly.

Comment: @stribizhev Yeah, I have edited that to a non-capturing group. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for regular expressions. just use `split`s and `join`s.

```
var s = '?cgan=1&product_cats=mens-jeans,shirts&product_tags=fall,classic-style&attr_color=charcoal,brown&attr_size=large,x-small&cnep=0';

var query = s.split('?')[1],
    pairs = query.split('&'),
    allowed = ['product_cats', 'product_tags', 'attr_color', 'attr_size'],
    results = [];

$.each(pairs, function(i, pair) {
  var key_value = pair.split('='),
      key = key_value[0],
      value = key_value[1];

  if (allowed.indexOf(key) > -1) {
    results.push(value);
  }
});

console.log(results.join(','));
```

($.each is from jQuery, but can easily be replaced if jQuery is not around)

Comment: This indeed would work. However I forgot to mention that I will not always know what the value of the attribute params (attr_?) will be unlike 'product_cats' and 'product_tags'. So I think I would need to rely on a regex for this one.

Comment: well, you can always change the allowed list/condition, e.g. `if (allowed.indexOf(key) > -1 || key.indexOf('attr_') === 0)` . but that's up to you. I generally try to avoid regexp when possible. I think that if something can be solved with string manipulations, it will be better read and perform better than regexp