# Get route params from url

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to retrieve a reset pw token from a link in an reset pw email. The link sends the user back to my node/angular app with the token which I am trying to get.

**Laravel API:** email template

```
            <td class="content">
               <a href="http://localhost:3000/reset-password?token={{$token}}">Reset Your Password</a>
            </td>
```

**Node/Angular app:** ResetPassword.ejs template: I am using an angular controller:

```
<div ng-controller="resetPasswordCtrl">
    ...stuff
</div>
```

reset password Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('resetPasswordCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', function($scope, $routeParams, $location) {

        console.log('ROUTE PARAMS', $routeParams); //object with a bunch of getters/setters
        console.log('ROUTE PARAMS', $routeParams.token); //undefined
        console.log('Location', $location.search('token'));  //LocationHashbangUrl
        console.log('Location', $location.search().token);  //true
        console.log('Location', $location.search()['token']); //true
        console.log('Route current params', $route); //empty route object 

    }]);
```

For the LocationHashbangUrl (`$location.search('token')`), I know I am getting the correct url with the token because the $$absUrl shows it.

[image]

Why am I unable to retrieve the `token` param using one of those methods shown in the controller?

Comment: What do you got wehn you `console.log($routeParams)` only ?

Comment: @Erazihel please see above edit

Comment: Can you post the code of your router ? Try using `$route` instead of `$routeParams` like this `console.log($route.current.params);`

Comment: @Erazihel see above plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out without using html5/angular routing, the typical methods

```
$location.search()
$routeParams
```

will not work.

Since I am passing the params and accessing my node app externally (from the e-mail link distributed from laravel), I needed to parse the URI using javascript.

I found [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript) which makes it easy. So, the following works:

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('resetPasswordCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $route, $window) {

        var getURIParams = function(variable) {
            var query = $window.location.search.substring(1);
            var vars = query.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                var pair = vars[i].split('=');
                if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
                    return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
                }
            }
            console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
        };
        console.log('VAR', getURIParams('token')); //my token param
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your $routeProvider?  You could just add token as a parameter there, and then $routeParams.token would do what you want.  Something like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/reset-password/:token')
```

That would mean your reset password url would look like this though:

```
http://localhost:3000/reset-password/{{$token}}
```

Comment: Kip, I am not using Angular routing for my app. I am using node. The token is coming back from my Laravel API through a link.