# Fetch data from URL using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to fetch the data from URL and use it. I Have 2 pages where I am redirecting the data from one page to other.

Here is the code for first page:

```
 <a href="product.html?catid={{child.name}}"> {{child.name}} </a>
```

on `product.html` how do I fetch the URL and the `catid` data.

If I use   `$location.path();` it is giving me an error

> $location not defined

How do I fetch the information from URL?

Comment: are you using any routing mechanism?

Comment: till Now I am not using any routing mechanism

Comment: Are you sure you are injecting $location? Also $location.path(); is for things after #. i.e product.html?catid={{child.name}}#thing=foo -> here $location.path() will give you something like "/thing=foo".

Comment: Also you should be using ng-href instead of href.

Comment: i would recommend you to use ui-router and pass the paramaters

Answer (score 0):

If on `product.html` you are not using angular or any routing mechanism you could always get the current url using the following:

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

From here on, you will have to parse the corresponding query string parameters (in your case `catid`) in order to obtain the desired value. The [`following thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript) could give you some example on how to achieve that.