# Regex in URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/src/profiles/project_part_2/Project2.html?score=6
```

I want to have the amount of score variable.

I did this:

```
var url_path = window.location;
```

That return the path:

```
http://localhost/src/profiles/project_part_2/Project2.html?score=6
```

Now I want to extract the amount of score.

Comment: You can parse query string first.then get your variable value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
location.href.match(/score=([^&]+)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a function that I use for query strings

```
function urlParam(name){
  var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  if (results==null){
     return null;
  }
  else{
     return results[1] || 0;
  }
}
```

So you would do

```
var score = urlParam('score');
```