# Creating an object out of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a string:

```
var str = "username:joe_1987;password:123456;email:joe@mailmail.com;"
```

Can I (or rather,) how can I create an object out of in a way that I can call it's parameters, something like:

`alert(obj.password)` and get `123456`

Comment: You can start by something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13419367/2479028

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse query string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend splitting on the semicolons in the string, giving you an array that will look like:

```
["username:joe_1987", "password:123456", "email:joe@mailmail.com"]
```

You can then apply the same idea to each element of this array, and then create the object. I've chucked a snippet below to explain:

```
var str = "username:joe_1987;password:123456;email:joe@mailmail.com;"

var splitBySemiColon = str.split(";");
splitBySemiColon.pop(); //Remove the last element because it will be ""

var obj = {};

for(elem in splitBySemiColon) {
    splitByColon = splitBySemiColon[elem].split(":");
    obj[splitByColon[0]] = splitByColon[1];
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Provided a live demo for you - https://repl.it/CtK8

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert, but something like this should work:

```
string = 'username:joe_1987;password:123456;email:joe@mailmail.com;';

array = string.split(';');
object = {};

for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(array[i] !== ''){
        console.log(array[i]);
        object[array[i].split(':')[0]] = array[i].split(':')[1];
    }
}

console.log(object);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oej2gznw/

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you're certain the desired values won't have `;` or `:`, you can just

```
var str = "username:joe_1987;password:123456;email:joe@mailmail.com;"
var obj = {};
str.split(';').forEach( function(segm) {
  if(segm.trim()) { // ignore empty string
    var spl = segm.split(':');
    obj[ spl[0] ] = spl[1];
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 var str = "username:joe_1987;password:123456;email:joe@mailmail.com;"
    var data=str.split(';');
    var obj={};
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      var propArray=data[i].split(':');
       obj[propArray[0]]=propArray[1]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight way. Just parse that string. For example:

```js
var str = "username:joe_1987;password:123456;email:joe@mailmail.com;"

var arr = str.split(';');
var o = {};
for (a in arr) {
  if (arr[a]) {
    o[arr[a].split(':')[0]]=arr[a].split(':')[1];
  }
}

console.log(o);
```