# Grabbing part of URL and sending to new URL

Tags: javascript, url, userid

My Javascript experience is limited, so I apologize in advance.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is make a button that grabs a part of the current URL (user ID) and then sends the user to a new URL with the user ID in it.

So, let's say the current URL is this:

```
owl.uwo.ca/account/12345/webpage.html/?userid=[6789]
```

And I need to send the user to this:

```
completestudent.ca/account?userid=[6789]&resourceid=[JG56J]
```

Am I on the right track with this code?

```
function completeModule(){
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    var userID = pathArray[4];
    var completeLink = "completestudent.ca/account"+userID+"&resourceid=[JG56J]";
    window.location.assign(completeLink)
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does it not work? For what you are doing (which is slightly odd to do in the front end), it should work.

Comment: I'd suggest to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

Comment: `location.pathname` does not return the parameters part, try with `.href` or directly with `.search`