# How to get query and hash from url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, url

I have a url `http://local.evibe-dash.in/tickets/123?ref=avl-error#10610`

I want to get `ref=avl-error` and `10610` in two variable

for Example somthing like that

```
var1 = 'avl-error';
var2 = 10610;
```

How can I get it in javascript or jQuery

Comment: Have you even tried solving this issue by yourself? Show us your code.

Comment: var t="http://local.evibe-dash.in/tickets/123?ref=avl-error#10610";
arr=t.split("=");
res=arr[1].split("#");
alert(res[0]+"       "+res[1]);

Comment: I don't know how to solve, that why I asked @mdziekon. I am not doing fun here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex in [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) you can find part of string you want.

```js
var url = "http://local.evibe-dash.in/tickets/123?ref=avl-error#10610";
var query = url.match(/ref=([^#]+)/)[1];
var hash = url.match(/#([^#]+)/)[1];
console.log(query, hash);
```

Comment: I want "ref=avl-error", not only avl-error for query . how can I get it.

Comment: @Vikash Use `var query = url.match(/ref=[^#]+/)[0]` instead it.

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad . Solved. can you please suggest me some good regex tutorials, My problem has solved but I didn't understand code completely.

Comment: @Vikash There are many turorial and answer in web that you can find them by search. However you can test any regex code in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) tool.

Comment: Thanks @mohammad. I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This was asked and answered multiple times on Stack.

Look at this posts:

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

[Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

Basicly you have to:

1. read query string: all after "?"
2. split string with "&" char into array
3. split all array elements with "="
4. decode values with decodeURIComponent

Please use stack before asking. And give some reputation to people on the links above.

Comment: That is easier to writing solution code instead of writing solution steps and duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function you get an array with query string key, it's value and the string after hash

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i; 
for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
        sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
    }
   if(window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    sParameterName[2] = url.match(/#([^#]+)/)[1];
        }
      }
     return sParameterName;
     };

    var a = getUrlParameter('your-query-string-key');
    console.log(a);
```