# JavaScript parameters from URL

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

result:

```
https://test.com/index.html?Event=90000002
```

how do I use Javascript to get `90000002` and put it in a variable?

Comment: the whole text including and after the `?` are in `window.location.search`

Comment: There are various querystring functions on stack.. just search and pick one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @Lain I tried, but I just don't understand it

Comment: fyi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Comment: `getParameterByName('Event')` would return 90000002, `window.location.search.substr(1)` would return Event=90000002 what is it that you don't understand about that?

Comment: good browsers have the `URL` object - look it up if you want to use it

Comment: @KevinKloet No idea, guess my brain turned off. Needed someone to explain it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .split() method

```
var data=url.split("=")[1]
```

Should return what you got after '='

Comment: Thanks! Way easier than the other answers.

Comment: @Preamas it's easy I can see but what if you have multiple params? meaning multiple such pairs, not only one.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary I guess I would search for another answer. I only have one parameter, so for me this is the perfect answer.

Comment: i would recommend getting the parameter by name like this: `getParameterByName('Event')`

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not optimized way but you can still do like this

Use `location` object and it's search property.

location.search will return `?Event=90000002`. Then use `substring` to get the value

```
var a = location.search;
console.log(a.substring(7,a.length))
```

Comment: Thanks, this also seems like a very easy solution which works for me.