# How do I create a link to pre-select a form option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code on another webpage on my site with a form (say on page **index.html**): [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmktg2dp/)

```
<select class="select form-control" id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="showForm()">
```

i.e a dropdown form.

I want to have a link on another webpage that will go to this page, and have the "Sales" option already selected.

```
<option value="1">
    Sales
</option>
```

from the drop down menu (instead of the current default option), how do I create this?

Answer (score 1):

Query parameters can be used to achieve the result you want, but you will need to parse the query parameter manually on your current page, since there is no standard JavaScript method for doing it.

You can write the following code on your page to automatically select the option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Parse your query parameters here, and assign them to a variable named `queryParams`
  var option = queryParams.type;
  $("#dropdown").val(option);
});
```

Now you can create an anchor with the URL of this page, e.g. `http://yourpage.url?type=1`, which will redirect to this page, and will automatically change the value of your dropdown accordingly.

Comment: you can parse the querystring like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript and maybe you have to trigger change event for additional functions-> $("#dropdown").trigger("change");

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle for this please :)

Comment: @SteveJobs - I've included my JavaScript in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmktg2dp/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You must add some kind of router functionality with Javascript in your site.

I think the simplest thing you could do it to have a script in that page that checks the url if it has say a `#bar` hash like so: `http://yoursite.com/foo.html#bar`.

```
<script>
// make sure you run this on DOM ready like in $.ready() in jQuery or in a script just before closing the body tag

if(window.location.hash === 'bar') {
  // add the selected attribute to the <option> you want
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`append()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjH_KawiqnUAhVItI8KHd0nBaoQFgg4MAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fappend%2F&usg=AFQjCNHOUufNEqoLDGnYJCokTxkU1HnY3w&sig2=GtsjQibI88oNwy0SioXssA) function of jquery .and pass `this` with in onchange function call .And also added with document.ready for create the link on document load with selected value

```js
function showForm(that){
var s = $(that).children('option:selected').text()
$('#link_box').append('<a href="'+s+'">'+s+'</a></br>')
}
$(document).ready(function(){ // for window load
showForm($('select'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="control-label" for="dropdown">
       What can we help you with?
       
      </label>
  <select class="select form-control" id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="showForm(this)">
       <option value="0" disabled>
   Select an option
       </option>
       <option value="1" selected>
     Sales
       </option>
       <option value="2">
     Complaints
       </option>
       <option value="3">
     Queries
       </option>
       <option value="4">
     Ideas
       </option>
      </select>
</div>
<div id="link_box">
<!-- its a link append  box-->
</div>
```