# Serverless read POST Variables in sensible way

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, twilio, serverless-framework

I have the following serverless lambda function code below...

```
export function incoming_calls(event, context, callback) {
  var util = require("util");

  const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

  //Determine message to give based on parameters given
  var theMessage = "Incoming Pool Service Leed";

  var querystring = require("querystring");
  var qMessage = querystring.stringify({message: theMessage});

  var whisperURL = "https://" + process.env.DOMAIN_NAME + "/twilio/whisper?" + qMessage;

  //twiml.say({ voice: 'woman' }, 'hello world!');
  twiml.dial({ record: 'true'}).number({url: whisperURL},'407-947-0503');
  //twiml.say({ voice: 'woman' }, 'This is a test!');

  //Useful Info
  var queryString = util.inspect(event.body);
  console.log("queryString="+queryString)
  sendemail("myemail@email.com","Incoming Call POST Request",queryString);

  callback(null, successXml(twiml.toString()));
}
```

This code works and sends me an email with the POST variables but as one long string looking like this...

`'Called=%2B15622222222&ToState=CA&CallerCountry=US&Direction=inbound&CallerState=CA&ToZip=90670&CallSid=CA47e5131dd5e7375190aaf5fab773a9b0&To=%2B15622221234&CallerZip=92606&CallerName=` ... etc

How do I convert the POST parameters I am receiving from Twilio into a nicer format, maybe an Array or Object instead of a String?

Answer (score 3):

The returned string looks like a simple query string, so you could just [parse the query string in vanilla js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript) or try to find another method to use instead of `toString()` to get the value you need.

Comment: How do you parse it though?

Comment: I see now somehow missed your link ... so many different answers!

Comment: Thanks michael just what I needed! You should post this as answer also.