# How to read parameter from url in Angular 5+ without Routing

Tags: angular, query-string

I have an angular landing page, the application will start with a bunch of query parameters, I want to read those parameter in the app.component, is there any way to read those parameter without using Router? I'm using UIRouter for the navigation.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the router? / Why cant you use the Router?

Comment: document.location ??

Comment: @Antoniossss maybe he is having a service worker installed wouldnt direct dom access destroy that?

Comment: How would I know?

Comment: you can use [location.search and parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091331/7291379)

Comment: .......but why?

Comment: because I'm using UIRouter for the navigation

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
window.location.href
```

and parse query string from there.