# Extract strings between occurences of a specific character

Tags: javascript, regex, string, find-occurrences

I'm attempting to extract strings between occurences of a specific character in a larger string.

For example:

The initial string is:

```
var str = "http://www.google.com?hello?kitty?test";
```

I want to be able to store all of the substrings between the question marks as their own variables, such as `"hello"`, `"kitty"` and `"test"`.

How would I target substrings between different indexes of a specific character using either JavaScript or Regular Expressions?

Comment: Are you aware that this is not a valid query string?

Comment: Maybe you will find this useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13419367/8173730

Comment: If `“test”` is extracted, why not `“http://www.google.com”`?

Comment: It's not meant to be used as a valid query string, I was just testing out grabbing information from a URL and playing around with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on `?` and use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) passing 1 as the parameter value.

That would give you an array with your values. If you want to create separate variables you could for example get the value by its index `var1 = parts[0]`

```js
var str = "http://www.google.com?hello?kitty?test";
var parts = str.split('?').slice(1);
console.log(parts);
var var1 = parts[0],
  var2 = parts[1],
  var3 = parts[2];
console.log(var1);
console.log(var2);
console.log(var3);
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked best for me as it was the most straight forward and easy to understand code snippet. I ended up simply calling the different index's inside the array rather than storing them in separate variables. I also like how it doesn't store the URL as the first index and if there aren't any ?'s in the string, it wont index anything.

Answer (score 0):

Quick note: that URL would be invalid. A question mark `?` denotes the beginning of a query string and key/value pairs are generally provided in the form `key=value` and delimited with an ampersand `&`.

That being said, if this isn't a problem then why not `split` on the question mark to obtain an array of values?

```
var split_values = str.split('?');
//result: [ 'http://www.google.com', 'hello', 'kitty', 'test' ]
```

Then you could simply grab the individual values from the array, skipping the first element.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It works great and does the job, I went with the other answer as it doesn't store the URL as the first index.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do it:

```
var components = "http://www.google.com?hello?kitty?test".split("?");
components.slice(1-components.length) // Returns: [ "hello", "kitty", "test" ]
```

Comment: This one worked great, but it also stored the URL as the first index in the array.

Answer (score 0):

using Regular Expressions

```js
var reg = /\?([^\?]+)/g;
var s = "http://www.google.com?hello?kitty?test";

var results = null;

while( results = reg.exec(s) ){
  console.log(results[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex solution! This does exactly what I was looking for, a bit more out of my realm of understanding compared to a JS only solution though.

Answer (score 0):

The general case is to use RegExp:

```
var regex1 = new RegExp(/\?.*?(?=\?|$)/,'g'); regex1.lastIndex=0;
str.match(regex1)
```

Note that this will also get you the leading `?` in each clause (no look-behind regexp in Javascript).

Alternatively you can use the sticky flag and run it in a loop:

```
var regex1 = new RegExp(/.*?\?(.*?)(?=\?|$)/,'y'); regex1.lastIndex=0;
while(str.match(regex1)) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the substring starting from the first question mark, then split by question mark

```js
const str = "http://www.google.com?hello?kitty?test";
const matches = str.substring(str.indexOf('?') + 1).split(/\?/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The solution works great, however it stores the URL in the array if no ?'s and additional terms are added to the end of the URL.