# How to make object of keys and values based on a string?

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have a following string:

```js
var str = "name=test1^assigned_to=12345678901112131415161718991234^business_service=99945678901112131415161718991211^EQ";
var obj = { name: 'test1',
            assigned_to: '12345678901112131415161718991234',
            business_service: '99945678901112131415161718991211'
          };
```

and would like to create object of specific keys and values from that string as is in my example, has anyone achieved similar thing? How?

Comment: love that querystring is reinvented to use ^ as a separator.

Comment: So split on ^, loop over. Split on = and set it

Comment: Isn't `short_description` supposed to be `name`? Like it is in the string?

Comment: yes, my mistake

Comment: https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/QWyRarg?editors=0012

Comment: Use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091331). Instead of splitting on `&`, split on `^`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = "name=test1^assigned_to=12345678901112131415161718991234^business_service=99945678901112131415161718991211^EQ";

let obj = {}
str.split('^').forEach(e => {
  let x = e.split('=');
  if (x[1])
    obj[x[0]] = x[1]
});

console.log(obj);
```

You can remove `if (x[1])` condition;

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)