# Any possible way to get url parameter from js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

any way to get url parameter that passed to js it self ?

example:

> https://xxxxxxx/sample.js?`key`=`valuehere`

the result i want to get: `var key = valuehere`

like php, it can be done with $_GET, but how it work it js ?

thanks in advance

Edit:

need to define the key in the js it self

```
function renderMe () {
    var value = getkeyvaluefromURL; // query param stored here
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"/api/render",
        method: "POST",
        data : { 'command' : 'list', 'key' = value},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#list').html(generateBoxList(data));
        },
    });
}
```

so the value need to passed to ajax query when it stored to js url.
all is one file js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the querystring from window.location.search

These answers demonstrate how to parse it to extract data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091331/4088472

Comment: thanks for reply,
but the result is ```Query variable key not found```.

Answer (score 0):

By using the below code you get the search parameters and are then able to search for the query by name

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
const key = params.get("key")
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of for URL parameter parsing/passing would be using the window.location.search property.

[www.example.com/?page_type=home%20page&color=black&size=xxxxl](http://www.example.com/?page_type=home%20page&color=black&size=xxxxl)

const queryString = window.location.search;

console.log(queryString);

Results: ?page_type=home%20page&color=black&size=xxxxl

Sources:
https://easyautotagging.com/javascript-get-url-parameter/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams